# Using Parsley.js with Meteor using HTML Code

Tags: meteor, parsley.js

I have been trying to use Parsley.js with Meteor, I can get it to work with a JS using a rendered function but I've had no luck when I use the HTML code approach.  Example code is given below:

```
<form class="form-horizontal frmParsley" role="form" parsley-validate>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Name" parsley-trigger="change" parsley-minlength="5" required />
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [docs](http://parsleyjs.org/documentation.html#javascript) at http://parsleyjs.org/documentation.html#javascript:

> Parsleys DOM-API is great. But not so great for complex forms, or dynamically generated forms.

Meteor's templates are dynamically generated forms. Therefore you need to initialize Parsley via JavaScript, in a `rendered` function.

There might be a way to initialize Parsley on `rendered` as if it were an initial page load, and therefore get it to recognize and parse the `parsley-` attributes, but such a method is undocumented and might be unreliable in the future.

Comment: This example meteor app might provide some leads on integration:  https://github.com/alanning/meteor-modal-example

Comment: That example shows how to use a jQuery widget . . . how does it relate to the original question?

Comment: It gives an example of doing what you described: using the Template rendered hook to initialize a 3rd-party component each time the template is rendered.  The use of a rendered-but-hidden sub-template ({{> editRolesForm}}) also allows the 3rd-party comp to recognize attributes.  I've found with the current "Spark" Meteor UI engine, there are quite a few places to trip up when trying to integrate 3rd party components.  The new Meteor UI engine should make it much simpler but I put together the above repo for people on the meteor-talk mailing list who were looking for an actual working example.