# Can't get parsley.js to work with meteor using javascript in rendered

Tags: meteor, parsley.js

I try to use parsley for validation with meteor following this question: [Using Parsley.js with Meteor using HTML Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292678/using-parsley-js-with-meteor-using-html-code)

I run meteor 0.6.6.3 on Ubuntu 13.10, added package jquery and added parsley 1.1.7 from atmosphere (https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/parsleyjs) with meteorite.

I also tested with the current version 1.2.2 of parsley  from client/lib (after removing parsleyjs with mrt).

Knowing that I can't use the HTML markup for validation I created a template like this

```
 <template name="new_customer">
   <form id="new_customer_form">
   <div class="newCustomer">         
      <div class="lookupcell">
         <input type="text" size="1" 
                name="new-customer-name" 
                id="new-customer-name" 
                class="new-customer-name" 
                placeholder="neue Firma/Person" 
                parsley-notblank="true" />
      </div>
      <div class="lookupcell">
         <input type="text" size="1" id="new-customer-email" 
                name="new-customer-email" 
                id="new-customer-email" 
                parsley-type="email" 
                parsley-trigger="keyup" 
                class="new-customer-email" placeholder="Email" />
      </div>
   </div>
   <div style="text-align: right;">
      <button type="submit">Add</button>   
      </div>
   </form>
</template>
```

and the following javascript for setup

```
Template.new_customer.rendered = function () {
   console.log("rendered new_customer");
   $new_customer_form = $( '#new_customer_form' );
   if (! $new_customer_form) { 
      console.log("form not found.");
      return; 
   }
   $new_customer_form.parsley();
   $new_customer_form.parsley( 'addItem', '#new_customer_name' );
};
```

meteor crashes on rendering at the last line when I try to add the field #new_customer_name with the following stacktrace

```
[09:44:11.969] "Exception from Deps afterFlush function: ParsleyForm.prototype.addItem@http://localhost:3000/packages/parsleyjs.js?ed9f338553f590de7edeb7b3e5ca8cb568f2e74d:1152
bind@http://localhost:3000/packages/parsleyjs.js?ed9f338553f590de7edeb7b3e5ca8cb568f2e74d:1295
$.fn.parsley@http://localhost:3000/packages/parsleyjs.js?ed9f338553f590de7edeb7b3e5ca8cb568f2e74d:1305
Template.new_customer.rendered@http://localhost:3000/client/X4Lizenzen.js?7d0644137e559b675577266ad6e2f78f087b3453:151
Template.__define__/partial/html</html<.rendered@http://localhost:3000/packages/templating.js?5944cd5e16b26fbf83959a0fe92d7754029a624d:181
scheduleOnscreenSetup/</<@http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?3a050592ceb34d6c585c70f1df11e353610be0ab:443
_.forEach@http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?13ab483e8a3c795d9991577e65e811cd0b827997:130
scheduleOnscreenSetup/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?3a050592ceb34d6c585c70f1df11e353610be0ab:441
.flush@http://localhost:3000/packages/deps.js?5ac28feec1f3e0539889ecde598dd9d01e408b41:265
"
```

The stack does not tell me what the actual problem is (or rather I don't understand :-)
So I wonder how the author of the linked question got his setup to work at all with the setup in rendered(). Any ideas anyone?

**Update:** It turns out I made a simple mistake which I did not spot until this morning. 
I had `id="new-customer-name"` in the template and tried to register the filed with parsley using `#new_customer_name`. This cannot work and what is more, hyphens cannot be used for id-strings. After correcting the error it worked.

Comment: Try running the code you have in your `.rendered` callback in your javascript console when the page has loaded instead and see what the error is there. It should give more detail on what it is

Comment: Thanks for the tip. When I run $( '#new_customer_form' ).parsley(); in the console I get back an object of type "parsleyForm" which looks good to me. On typing $( '#new_customer_form' ).parsley( 'addItem', '#new_customer_name' ); I get 'TypeError: a is null' . I have no clue what this is supposed to mean here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to add the data-parsley-validate as given below. if its working without using that let me know. I am wondering how did it render with using data-parsley-validate in form.

> form id="new_customer_form" data-parsley-validate